# I need help (Api calls in React Js Hooks) Why is this nort working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-effect

I need help (Api calls in React Js Hooks) Why is this nort working?
I need to call the values from that API

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Customers() {
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactstarter-app.herokuapp.com/api/customers')  **API CALLS**
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(customers => setCustomers(customers))
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Customers</h2>
        <ul>
            {customers.map((customer) => {
                return <li key={customer.id}>{customer.firstName} {customer.lastName}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
}

export default Customers;
```

Comment: You have a const named "customers", but in the fetch, you use the res.json() as: `.then(customers => setCustomers(customers))`. You should call it something else, like: `.then(data => setCustomers(data))`

Comment: Thanks for the response but i don't quite get it. Can you make changes to code and paste please

Comment: @SagarKattel I think the problem is that API blocked by CORS. Try to catch the error first

Comment: @SagarKattel try with this API instead `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://reactstarter-app.herokuapp.com/api/customers`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't a solution, but I cannot paste code to comment, so I have to post an answer:

```
function Customers() {
    // this is where you declare the "customers" const
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactstarter-app.herokuapp.com/api/customers')  **API CALLS**
        .then(res => res.json())
        // this is where you should change the "customers" to "data"
        // because of the variable name conflict
        .then(data => setCustomers(data))
}, [])
```

Comment: Its not working please help

Comment: Okay, another problem is that "https://reactstarter-app.herokuapp.com/api/customers" disabled the CORS requests. If you try it with another API, like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", you should get the response from the API.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/84nt3x16/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to map through a null state and probably getting an error, use conditional rendering to avoid the error and render the customers after the api request:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Customers() {
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactstarter-app.herokuapp.com/api/customers')  **API CALLS**
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(customers => setCustomers(customers))
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Customers</h2>
        {!customers ? <h2>Loading customers...</h2> :
         <ul>
            {customers.map((customer) => {
                return <li key={customer.id}>{customer.firstName} {customer.lastName}</li>
            })}
        </ul>}
    </div>
);
}

export default Customers;
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-oskar-y36cid?file=/src/App.js    Can you help me here?

Comment: It looks like you need to enable CORS in your server. if you're using express, look here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html